# Write to files in Delphi

Tags: file, delphi

I'm doing a program in Delphi, writing in all kinds of files, either text or executable:

```
var
  openfile: TextFile;
begin
      AssignFile(openfile, 'test.exe');
      Append(openfile);
      WriteLn(openfile,'[test]hi world[test]');
      CloseFile(openfile);
end;
```

How can I improve this?

Comment: There are other ways using native file handles, but the way you have done it is the recommended one.

Comment: Although it might not be recommenced to write text to a file with a .EXE extension ,-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. I would add `try..finally` so that the file will be properly closed even in the case of exception (hopefully my remembrance of the syntax isn't too rusty):

```
var
  openfile: TextFile;
begin
      AssignFile(openfile, 'test.exe');
      Append(openfile);
      try
          WriteLn(openfile,'[test]hi world[test]');
      finally
          CloseFile(openfile);
      end;
end;
```

also, you say you want to write binary files as well as text files.. so don't use `TextFile`. The "modern" way would be to use `TFileStream`:

```
with TFileStream.Create('test.exe', fmOpenWrite) do
try
  Seek(0,soFromEnd);
  Write(...);
finally
  Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Please note that AssignFile routines are very old fashioned. Consider using OOP approach using streams, like

```
var
  f: TFileStream;
begin
  f:=TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate);
  try
    f.WriteBuffer(Pointer(SourceString)^, Length(SourceString));
  finally
    f.Free;
  end;
end;
```

(SourceString in this case should be AnsiString. It needs a little change for Unicode)

Comment: What's wrong with using TStringStream and copying from that?

Comment: TStringStream does not work directly with the file (not suitable if you work with large files) and you can't change just specific part of it - you have to load and save whole file.

Comment: I am not sure we are on the same page here. What I am saying is: to copy a string, why can't you use a TStringStream and then CopyFrom there. TStringStream allows you to seek and read specific strings, so it does precisely what you say it doesn't do. Or I am missing something.

Comment: This topic is "Write to files". TStringStream is a memory stream, you have to load whole file into memory, change it and save it = overwrite whole file.